# Azure Pipelines - export variable from Python script task to use in Powershell script task

Tags: python-3.x, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a variable defined in my Python script task in Azure pipelines.

```
variable = "True"
```

I want to use this variable in the next task which is a Powershell script task.

How can I achieve this using Azure YAML pipelines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Task Output Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) already?
e.g.

```yaml
steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  name: pythonTask
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      someVar = "True"
      print("someVar = " + someVar)
      print("##vso[task.setvariable variable=someVar]" + someVar)

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "python var = $(someVar)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Killian! This was exactly what I wanted.